# How to specify the default value if the binding fails?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a DrawingBrush as follow :-

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="MY_ICON" Viewbox="0,0,39.125,39.125" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=uiEntityViews:BaseView}, Path=Color}" Geometry="F1M19.5625,0.999954C29.8144,0.999954 38.125,9.31053 38.125,19.5625 38.125,29.8142 29.8143,38.1249 19.5625,38.1249 9.31073,38.1249 1,29.8142 1,19.5625 1,9.31053 9.31064,0.999954 19.5625,0.999954z">
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                <Pen DashCap="Square" EndLineCap="Flat" LineJoin="Round" MiterLimit="10" StartLineCap="Flat" Thickness="2">
                    <Pen.Brush>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.849422,0.849423" StartPoint="0.150577,0.150578">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF657783" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.146"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF2C4758" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Pen.Brush>
                    <Pen.DashStyle>
                        <DashStyle/>
                    </Pen.DashStyle>
                </Pen>
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

I used the above brush inside the style as the following:-

```
<Style x:Key="NODE_ICON" TargetType="Rectangle">
<Setter Property="Fill">
  <Setter.Value>
    <DrawingBrush TileMode="None">
      <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
          <GeometryDrawing Brush="{StaticResource MY_ICON}">
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
              <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1,1" />
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
          </GeometryDrawing>

          <DrawingGroup>
            <DrawingGroup.Transform>
              <TranslateTransform X="0.2" Y="0.2" />
            </DrawingGroup.Transform>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{StaticResource NODE_ICON}">
              <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1,1" />
              </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            </GeometryDrawing>
          </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingGroup>
      </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Right now, I am getting this error - `System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='Views.UIEntityViews.BaseView', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=Color; DataItem=null; target element is 'GeometryDrawing' (HashCode=3377278); target property is 'Brush' (type 'Brush')`.

It seems that the binding is not working. Is there a way to specify the default value for color, lets say  `<GeometryDrawing Brush="{StaticResource ROADM_ICON, color=Gray}">` if the binding fails?

Comment: What about using a converter, binding to that, and the code can determine a fallback

Comment: Can you provide any outline or links on how to implement this using converters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Carmine suggested using FallbackValue, I was able to make it work making following changes:-

```
<GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=uiEntityViews:CanvasLinkConnectionPointBaseView}, Path=MeSiteColor, FallbackValue=Gray}" Geometry="F1M19.5625,0.999954C29.8144,0.999954 38.125,9.31053 38.125,19.5625 38.125,29.8142 29.8143,38.1249 19.5625,38.1249 9.31073,38.1249 1,29.8142 1,19.5625 1,9.31053 9.31064,0.999954 19.5625,0.999954z">
```

Answer (score 3):

Use FallbackValue`.....<GeometryDrawing Brush="{StaticResource NODE_ICON, FallbackValue=Gray}">`

Comment: I tried using FallBackValue in GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=uiEntityViews:CanvasLinkConnectionPointBaseView}, Path=MeSiteColor, FallBackValue=Gray}"  but I am getting the error as Error 283 Unknown property 'FallBackValue' for type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' encountered while parsing a Markup

Comment: Thanks Carmine, I was able to make it work using FallbackValue, but in a different place than you suggested.